# Is this a plot of Isp vs propellant mass fraction for a SSTO vehicle?

Tags: reference-request, specific-impulse, mass-fraction

Whilst trying to find some information on SSTO designs, I came across this chart:

[image: Propellant mass fraction vs propellant specific impulse for single-stage-to-orbit rocket]

It was used in an ancient forum thread by as part of an SSTO discussion, but the poster didn't cite the paper they'd taken it from. I got as far as identifying that RBCC meant [rocket-based combined cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-based_combined_cycle), but that was about it.

So. Does this really show Isp vs propellant fraction *required for an SSTO*, or was the original poster misinformed? (and so what *is* it showing?)

It would also be nice to know if that line should be straight, or at least curved in only one direction, and if anyone any idea what paper the plot was taken from I'd like to know.

Comment: If you are asking about the thick black line that starts near 1.0 and drops to 0.55, It appears to be a plot of the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) where $\Delta v$ is fixed (possibly 10 km/s) and the parameter $1 - \frac{m_0}{m_f}$ is plotted against ISP. See also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propellant_mass_fraction)

Comment: @AJN I'm guessing more like 7.6 km/s as the fixed $\Delta v$, [as this nearly replicates the curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1-exp%28-7600%2F9.80665*1%2Fx%29+from+200+to+1000). I guessed 480 seconds as the Isp that requires a propellant mass fraction of 0.8 and solved for $\Delta v$.

Comment: ... and not only $\Delta v$ is fixed, but also the thrust is fixed (a.k.a. gravitational drag is neglected)

Comment: @asdfex Your wolfram alpha link is messed up in your comment from about 10 minutes ago. It can be a pain in the SE to get those links correct. There are bugs in how SE interprets links.

Comment: @asdfex In this case, changing the asterisk to %2A works: https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%29%3D1-exp%28-7600%2F%28x%2A9.81%29%29+for+x%3D100..1000 . Sometimes you have to change characters such as open and close parentheses, asterisks, plus signs, minus signs and spaces to their hex equivalent (e.g., %2A for an asterisk) in order for SE to get the raw link right.

Comment: I've found that the open-square-bracket description close-square-bracket open-parenthesis link close-parenthesis is sometimes less problematic. Close parentheses are still problematic.

Comment: The curvature is simple: It has to be S-shaped: For low ISP it has to be tangent to 1 (a lot of fuel and nothing else), for very high ISP it is asymptotic to 0 (almost no fuel). http://wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%29%3D1-exp%28-7600%2F%28x%2A9.81%29%29+for+x%3D100..1000

Comment: @asdfex not just gravitational drag, but aerodynamic drag, wing and structural mass overhead, etc, considering the sort of vehicle that would use "rocket based combined cycle" propulsion.

Comment: @asdfex You're correctly describing the factors that shape the curve but how do you think this is S shaped??

Comment: Bothers me that the graph cuts off at around 1000 seconds...

Comment: @ikrase what would you put after the 1000 seconds bit, though? Project Orion?

Comment: @LorenPechtel An s-shaped curve is a curve that first bends in one direction, then the other. Doesn't need to resemble an actual letter S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More precisely, this is a plot of the mass fraction required to achieve some target delta-v. As David Hammen points out, the curve seems to be a closer match to ~7.6 km/s, which would would be in the territory of a high-energy first stage rather than a SSTO. This would actually be fairly close to an Atlas V core equivalent.

A typical rocket needs ~10 km/s of delta-v to reach orbit. An air-breathing vehicle with its slow climb and long path through the atmosphere will need more. Realistically, you'll have different curves for different propulsion technologies and vehicle types, each accounting for the differences in gravity and aerodynamic losses. [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qjuyqnvf5i) an attempt based on [this derivation from Henry Spencer and Bob Zubrin](https://web.archive.org/web/20220131115058/http://www.islandone.org/Propulsion/SCRAM-Spencer1.html) and the RBCC performance shown in that plot. With L/D of 5 and average acceleration of 0.5*g*, taking the "equivalent effective specific impulse" from your plot as the specific impulse at $V_{final}/2$ and a somewhat wider range for chemical rocket performance:
[image: Delta-v versus specific impulse]

Comment: And note that 7.6km/sec isn't actually going to get you into orbit.  It looks like the author was looking at an ideal situation--no losses whatsoever.  I'm ok with omitting gravity and drag losses in this situation but you can't avoid the losses of climbing to your desired orbit.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I do note that, twice.